# Xcode 11.2 swift 13.2 An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

i am trying to send remote notification using one signal and i made all certificates right when i run application and check one signal i got this "We haven't detected any subscribed users yet for this platform" and i found this in my log in xcode "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?" and i have been searching online all the day and i tried every solution i found and it did not work  i also done this in info.plist

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

[image]

Comment: It might not be you.  The server is closing the connection here.  Error 9816 is "server closed session with no notification".  If you haven't tried, try adding the NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion=TLSv1.0 key/value to App Transport Security.

Comment: added it and still got same error

Comment: You might need to look at the Wireshark traces and see what TLS version you are sending versus what the server is requiring.  Have you contacted anyone at onesignal.com and see if they have issues with their SSL cert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the problem is one signal does not open in my country , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different network.